# listview doesn't appear, no errors

Tags: android, json, listview

I am making a listview, which shows data from a server. I get no errors in LogCat, but my ListView doesn't appear. This is my code:

```
   package com.imptmd.charliemacdonald.desleutelaar;

  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ListAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;


  public class SlotenFragment extends ListFragment {

private ProgressDialog nDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://charlenemacdonald.com/sloten.json";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SLOTEN = "slotenlijst";
private static final String TAG_SLOT = "Slot";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray sloten= null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> slotenLijst;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sloten, container, false);

    slotenLijst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);


    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String Slot = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textviewslotnaam))
                    .getText().toString();


            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    SlotInfoScherm1.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_SLOT, Slot);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    });




    new GetSloten().execute();


    // Calling async task to get json
    return rootView;

        }

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetSloten extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        nDialog.setMessage("Even geduld a.u.b., studenten worden geladen...");
        nDialog.setCancelable(false);
        nDialog.show();


    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                sloten = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_SLOTEN);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < sloten.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = sloten.getJSONObject(i);

                    String Slot = c.getString(TAG_SLOT);


                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> sloten = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    sloten.put(TAG_SLOT, Slot);


                    // adding contact to contact list
                    slotenLijst.add(sloten);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (nDialog.isShowing())
            nDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), slotenLijst,
                R.layout.sloten_info, new String[] { TAG_SLOT}, new int[] { R.id.textviewslotnaam});

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }



}






    }
```

The INTERNET permission is already added in the Manifest, just as WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE and INTERNAL STORAGE. I get no errors in LogCat. The only error I get is in the ADB 'ADB rejected connection to client'. Is that why my ListView doesn't appear? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi can you show the error here :)

Comment: @Bhavdip He said there is no error.

Comment: if `makeServiceCall` returns null, your ArrayList will remain empty

Comment: Can you tell me Did you saw this Log in  Logcat  Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

Comment: Hi  In log cat can you see this log Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

Comment: Ehm, I see my JSON data from my JSON file @BhavdipPathar

Comment: try to restart your ide so that u can see logcat.

Comment: `new String[] { TAG_SLOT}` must be the list of column names that will be added to the Map associated with each item. In your case, its better to use a custom adapter instead of `SimpleAdapter`

Comment: show your layout `fragment_sloten`

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you update you code and test the below logic what you received.

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog 
        if (nDialog.isShowing())
            nDialog.dismiss();
        /** 
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView 
         * */ 
        Log.d("DataSize: ",""+slotenLijst.size());

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), slotenLijst,
                R.layout.sloten_info, new String[] { TAG_SLOT}, new int[] { R.id.textviewslotnaam});

        setListAdapter(adapter);


    }
```

Let us know what you get in log cat "DataSize".

Comment: I get the error that the String cannot be applied to (String, int)

Comment: If the size is greater than zero then you defiantly collect the json data in to the  array list, In next you have to see in SimpleAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onCreateView(...)` to be:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sloten, container, false);

   slotenLijst = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

   new GetSloten().execute();


   // Calling async task to get json
   return rootView;

}


// ListFragment implement this in default
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{
        //getting values from selected ListItem
        String Slot = ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textviewslotnaam))
                .getText().toString();


        // Starting single contact activity
        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                SlotInfoScherm1.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_SLOT, Slot);

        startActivity(in);

    }
});
```

and your fragment layout `fragment_sloten` could be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#00FF00"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

          ... ...         
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help!